# Adding Jekyll to an existing website

Tags: jekyll

I have a simple website and tried to add a Jekyll blog in it in a new folder `blog` thus I have run `jekyll new blog` in the folder `/path`. However when I'm running the command `jekyll build` in `/path` I have these errors:

```
$ jekyll build
Configuration file: none
Source: /path
Destination: /path/_site
Generating... 
Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in blog/_posts/2015-06-14-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in blog/index.html does not exist.
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error converting 'blog/css/main.scss'.
Conversion error: File to import not found or unreadable: /blog/_sass/base.scss. Load paths: on line 47
```

I solved the first problem (`Configuration file: none`) by moving `_config.yml`in the parent folder, however I still have problems when requesting layout using

```
---
layout: default
---
```

The imports in `main.scss`are also not working (last error).

If I'm doing the same command `jekyll build` in `/path/blog`after moving again `_config.yml`, I have no errors. Does someone know how to be able to do a `jekyll build`in the parent folder with the configuration I have? Do I have to entirely change the architecture of my website to include a Jekyll blog in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `config.yml` is in `/path` with

```
source: /_jekyll
destination: /blog
baseurl: /blog
```

Your jekyll sources are in `/path/_jekyll`.

And you generated files will be in `/path/blog`.

Ready to deploy !

Comment: Works with source `_jekyll` and destination `blog` without slashes, thanks for your help!

Comment: This ended up working, but now my _sass folder is broken. I get a conversion error `Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'style.scss': Error: File to import not found or unreadable: reset. on line 5:1 of style.scss >> @import "reset"; ^ ` this was after I added `blog\_sass` to the `sass_dir` Any advice?